# PHP SOAP server doesn't correctly process UTF-8 strings from a C# SOAP client

Tags: c#, php, soap, utf-8

I have a PHP SOAP server (using nuSOAP) that I consume with a C#-based application.

When the C# application submits a request, the strings are UTF-8 encoded.  I verified using a network sniffer that the byte sequences are valid UTF-8.  However, when PHP gets then and I post them to the database or send them by email, it appears to be printed like standard ASCII, the UTF encoding bytes are treated as characters.

I have the same issue with the C# app receiving UTF-8 from the SOAP server.  .NET interprets each byte as a CHAR instead of a BYTE.  I had to write a small function that converts each CHAR to a BYTE and then converts that to a UTF-8 string and that's working perfectly.

The question is, what do I need to do on the PHP server side to correctly process the incoming SOAP requests as UTF-8 for MySQL and the `mail()` function?  I've tried `utf8_encode()` and `utf8_decode()` but those mangle the string even worse.

Comment: That's hardly surprising (that you've got interoperability issues). See http://72.249.21.88/nonintersecting/2006/11/15/the-s-stands-for-simple/. It's written humorously but it's funny because it's true.

Comment: I actually read that way back at the beginning when I was working on getting the two to work.  Even worse, I had to get a working Public Key/Private system working with the server doing the signing and the client validating. That was a real pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling with this all day, I found the solution.

nuSOAP was automatically running `utf8_decode` on incoming SOAP requests.  After I disabled that feature and made sure I used `mysqli->set_charset('utf8')` everything appears to be working now.

Now I'd just like to know why .NET doesn't interpret the SOAP response strings properly...

Answer (score 0):

You Can use 
$server = new soap_server();
$server->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
 for decoding

Comment: I was already doing that part, it was the $server->decode_utf8 = false I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

In the file nusoap.php, around line 5480, you should change:

FROM: `$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';`

TO: `$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';`

After that, your web service will also be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

And, in the line 151  (nusoap.php) change:

```
//var $soap_defencoding = 'ISO-8859-1';
var $soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
```